# devise token auth find user with password reset token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise-token-auth

I'm using devise token auth and I'm setting up password reset process. When I click the reset link in the email, it has the url parameter `reset_password_token=hK3yxC1zVZCbWL8WgqKM` but when in the rails console I do

```
2.5.1 :004 > User.first.reset_password_token
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => "ab432079e4e8aacfa0ecb5df17a7cea169990b0e0809ea9553248064220471a7"
```

These tokens do not match but they should. Is it encoded somehow and if so how can I find a user which has a token?

Answer (score 1):

What is stored in the database, is the [`Digest::SHA256`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html).

```
token = "hK3yxC1zVZCbWL8WgqKM"
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest token
#⇒ "ae74625ac2357c8f2de0f3f52647aaee191dbba5d383f8ec5822cfec5c24384e"
```

One obviously cannot revert it back to token, one can only `hexdigest` the token that came from the user and compare it against what is stored in the database.

Comment: Okay, so how will I be able to find a user with the matching token?